# Configuration Profiles - iOS

Tags: ios, mdm, configuration-profile

With the encoded plist file from the MDM Vendor,I have created two Push Certificate so that I do have two unique topic for my configuration profile. With this I create two configuration profile (.mobileconfig) with Wi-Fi payload. In each profile I create a connection to two individual wifi networks. When both the profiles are installed into the mobile, how do I know which network will be connected? Can I set any preference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A side note: Two push certificate with different topics generally should be used for two different customers. Each device can enroll into just one MDM server and will use only one topic. Also, they are unrelated to configuration profiles (meaning that nothing in push certificates influence configuration profiles).

Answering your question:

- The only control over a connection which you have is "AutoJoin" key for a WiFi network.
  if both networks have AutoJoin keys, I don't think that you have any control over which network will be connected (if both of them in range).
- I am not sure, but I believe the network with the best signal quality is get connected in such a case.